# Using progress bars in vb to show a specific time frame

Tags: vb.net

I want to use progress bars for my project throughout, since it is very much necessary, for the main part of this game I am creating, however, to get a GOOD grade at A Level, you need to be able to show variation and to not have a large amount of data replication, is there any, remotely easy understandable way to allow for a button when pressed to allow for the progress bar to be completed for me in a 5 second time period. Please let me know. If you need any code It may be rather extensive a long, because I went a really unorthodox way about this originally. But just don't really want to have about 15-20 timers in the end product.

```
 Private Sub ButtonClick2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonClick2.Click

        money = money + (4 * LevelMultiplier2)
        label_avail_money.Text = Math.Round(money, 2).ToString("N2")
```

```
Public Class Form1
 Dim money As Decimal = 0
 Dim LevelMultiplier2 As Decimal = 1
```

Basically this is what is for this button, all I need for is for 1. For the Calculation to be ran 5 seconds prior to when the button is pressed and also to have a progress bar running simultaneously with the button press too. Hope this helps, also putting this into some form of code now may help me more to resolve this issue :)

Comment: Since you're referring to a *button pressed*, you need to specify your UI framework. Btw, if you have async/await available, you just need to `await Task.Delay(1000)` five times in a loop.

Comment: Or `await Task.Delay(100)` 50 times, if you want the UI to render a *smoother* progress.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you once again, for helping, I will try that, sorry for late response too. I will let you know if it does end up working, and if not, I will add in the code in the initial post

Comment: All right. Note, however, that I don't really know what you're doing/planning to do and that `Task.Delay()` is not exactly intended as a *precision stopwatch*.

Comment: @Jimi hopefully this edited version should allow you to open up as such? I put an explanation at the bottom, and hopefully you can understand where I am coming from. If you want the code that I used to get the other one working I can give you that, although this one instead of doing it when the button is clicked every time you purchase something that allows it to be running all the time. This is done with the `Timer.Start()` function and once is running is always running.

Comment: Nope. I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Performing a calculation of sort 5 seconds **before** a Button is pressed is clearly not possible, so you probably meant to generate a progress in a UI (it looks like WinForms) while a Button is **disabled** and re-enable the Button after this calculation is terminated. But you're not showing what this calculation should be, since there's no iteration anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @Jimi not 5 second before 5 seconds after, however the only way I can find is by literally doing ,.sleep which just makes the whole form sleep. I will edit again. I am doing 2 things at once so it may take me a while to reply but will try to reply asap, for additional explaining, After the button is pressed, I want to wait 5 seconds and then it completes the action without it doing `Time.Tick(500)` then it does it if that makes sense, also the iteration I don't have yet, because I am still in the process of getting my head round what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Jimi, the last thing is that I actually want the calculation displayed `money = money + (4 * LevelMultiplier2)` here to be done 5 seconds after. Hopefully this makes more sense?

Comment: If you want to generate an output from your calculation after a delay, then make the `Button.Click` event handler `async` (add the `async` keyword as in: `private async sub Button_Click(sender as object, a as EventArgs)`) and add `await Task.Delay(5000)` before the code that shows the result. You also have to disable the button before the delay and re-enable it after.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` and add `Imports System.Reactive.Linq` - then you can do this:

```
Private Sub ButtonClick2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonClick2.Click

    ButtonClick2.Enabled = False

    Observable _
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0 / 100.0)) _
        .Take(100) _
        .ObserveOn(Me) _
        .Subscribe(
            Sub(x) ProgressBar1.Value = x + 1,
            Sub()
                money = money + (4 * LevelMultiplier2)
                label_avail_money.Text = Math.Round(money, 2).ToString("N2")
                ButtonClick2.Enabled = True
            End Sub)
End Sub
```

That code nicely animates the progress bar and then fills in the `label_avail_money.Text` value.